# Сделать static метод, который распарсит строку в Python

Tags: python, классы

Необходимо создать статический метод some_string(), который распарсит строку и присвоит содержащие атрибуты нужным свойствам. Свойства будут разделены тире.

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, salary):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.salary = salary

    @staticmethod
    def some_string(parse_stirng):
        firstname, lastname, salary =  parse_stirng.split("-")
        return firstname, lastname, salary



emp1 = Employee("Sam", "Ragnarson", 35000)
print(emp1.firstname)
print(emp1.salary)

emp2 = Employee("Sam", "Ragnarson", 35000)
print(emp2.from_string("Mary-Steve-40000"))
```

Результат кода должен быть следующим:

emp1.firstname ➞ "Sam"

emp1.salary ➞ 35000

emp2.firstname ➞ "Mary"

emp2.lastname ➞ "Steve"

Не могу разобраться как из статического метода присвоить со строки соответствующие значения в свойства экземпляра класса firstname, lastname, salary ведь static существует вне зависимости от класса и объекта класса.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подобный статический метод должен создавать новый объект с заданными свойствами, вызывая конструктор класса. Можно сказать - альтернативный способ создания объекта

```
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, firstname, lastname, salary):
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.salary = salary

    @staticmethod
    def from_string(parse_stirng):
        firstname, lastname, salary = parse_stirng.split("-")

        # Создаем объект Employee и возвращаем его
        return Employee(firstname, lastname, salary)


emp2 = Employee.from_string("Mary-Steve-40000")

print(emp2.firstname)
```

Comment: "Подобный статический метод должен создавать новый объект с заданными свойствами" - необязательно, может просто менять комплектом атрибуты уже готового объекта.

Comment: либо атрибуты класса, либо должен получать объект в качестве аргумента вызова, и тогда он перестанем быть статическим

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Я если честно и не знал что через статический метод можно создать объект.

Comment: Он ничем не отличается от любой другой функции :) Кстати, можете в нем заменить Employee на `__class__` , тоже будет работать, именно потому, что он метод конкретного класса